# Trouble with array pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was solving last years GATE question paper where i am stuck with this question

> What does the following fragment of C-program print?

```
char c[]="GATE2011";
char *p =c;
printf ("%s", p+p[3]-p[1]);
```

The answer is '2011'

I am aware that in c, array variables are pointer to first address of the array. My logical answer was 'E2011', but the output is *2011*

Can someone explain the pointer mathematics involved in this?

Comment: I think that you need to re-read your book on pointers. You are mixing pointer arithmetic with characters. This will lead into all sort of problems in the future if you go down this route.

Comment: @EdHeal This was an exam (GATE) question. hopefully not some production code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p[3] = A

p[1] = E

E - A = 4

hence p + 4 = address of 2

hence it prints 2011

Comment: thanks. i spent time in complex solutions and forgot about looking into basics. i will now remember this solution.

Comment: no problem. good luck with your gate exam and related activities

Answer (score 7):

This problem has *much* more to do with [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) than it does with pointers.

```
p[3] == 'E' == 69 (decimal)
p[1] == 'A' == 65 
p[3]-p[1] = 4

p+4 = A string starting at the 4th character.

p[] = [0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8]
       G   A   T   E   2   0   1   1  \0
```

Hence, p[4] = **2011**

Comment: thanks.. i spent last night manipulating addresses, i completely forgot about ASCII values.